# Timber: Featured posts excepts using ACF are the original posts

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have a ACF field which allows the admin to select related articles to the post that they are editing.

I am passing this to my view by:

```
$data['post'] = $post;
$data['related_posts'] = Timber::get_posts(get_field('related'));
Timber::render('single-blog-2019.twig', $data);
```

I am then looping over this in the template:

```
{% for related_post in related_posts %}
    <div class="third {% if loop.first %} mr-15 {% elseif loop.last %} ml-15 {% else %} ml-15 mr-15 {% endif %}">
    <div class="card bg-color-white p-20">
            <h2 class="font-size-24 font-color-dark-teal font-weight-500">{{ related_post.post_title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ related_post.preview }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The issue is getting the related article excerpt, the `{{ related_post.post_title }}` works fine, shows the correct post title for each related post, but, `{{ related_post.preview }}` appears to display the main posts excerpt, not for each of the related articles.

Comment: sorry, this was a mistake when copy & pasting, I was actually using an include but removed it from this example. Updating the questions now.

Comment: @ChrisBratherton Insted of `related_post.preview` try once `related_post.post_excerpt`

Comment: @WPDeveloper Thanks, however, I am relying on the fact that a post excerpt may not exist, I can see from the documentation that the .preview method would take this into account and display X chars from the main content instead if no excerpt is defined.

Comment: Your most welcome. I have done this previously, so i thought may be this would help you.